# Shader working on desktop but not on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I've been trying to figure out why my shader doesn't work on Android while it does on desktop. With not working I mean the shader makes the texture unable to be seen. Here's the code of my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;
varying float randomFloat;

uniform vec3 dif_color;
uniform sampler2D u_sampler2D;

vec4 color_right;
vec4 color_left;
vec4 color_bottom;
vec4 color_top;

vec3 colorNeighbors;
float neighbors;

void main(){
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_sampler2D, v_texCoord0) * v_color;
    ivec2 texSize = textureSize(u_sampler2D, 0);
    ivec2 texIndex = ivec2(int(v_texCoord0.x * float(texSize.x)), int(v_texCoord0.y * float(texSize.y)));
    color_right = texelFetch( u_sampler2D, texIndex + ivec2(1, 0), 0).rgba;
    color_left = texelFetch( u_sampler2D, texIndex + ivec2(-1, 0), 0).rgba;
    color_top = texelFetch( u_sampler2D, texIndex + ivec2(0, 1), 0).rgba;
    color_bottom = texelFetch( u_sampler2D, texIndex + ivec2(0, -1), 0).rgba;

    if(color_right.a != 0){ neighbors++; }
    if(color_left.a != 0){ neighbors++; }
    if(color_top.a != 0){ neighbors++; }
    if(color_bottom.a != 0){ neighbors++; }

    vec3 colorNeighbors = (color_right.rgb + color_left.rgb + color_top.rgb + color_bottom.rgb) / neighbors;

    if((color_right.a != 0 || color_left.a != 0 || color_top.a != 0 || color_bottom.a != 0) && color.a == 0){
        color.rgba = vec4(.1 + .3 * randomFloat + colorNeighbors,1.0);
        }
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

I've read many similar questions to mine. Answers to these advise adding a certain line: precision mediump float; and using floating points instead of integers. I've applied this to my code, but with no different result from not working.
Other answers are totally irrelevant to my code. I assume the problem in my code lies in this line:

```
ivec2 texSize = textureSize(u_sampler2D, 0);
```

When I remove this line (along with the lines dependent on this variable) the shader operates, but of course not in the way I want it to.

So, maybe someone knows a different way to get the texture size? But I'd also like to know what causes the shader to disfunction?

Comment: You really should not be using `textureSize` and `texture2D` in the same shader.

Comment: Try something like the Mali Offline Compiler - you can test your shaders compile as part of your build process rather than failing at runtime (https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/graphics-development-tools/mali-offline-compiler/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Khronos specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/textureSize.xhtml) `textureSize` is available only in OpenGL ES SL 3.00. If you want to use it you should rewrite your code for OpenGL ES [SL] 3 format.

Also, check shader compilation log to see if there are other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use textureSize. Use the same values in a Vector2 uniform.
Be careful to send another float uniform with the devicePixelRatio. if don't, the texture in devices with retina display will looks to half size.